# jquery nextAll() function, check if there is a next

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, traversal

How can I test if there is a next ,because this does not want to work

It counts 3 elements all the time for some reason?

```
$("body "+content).on("keypress","form.fcheckoutform :input.aantal",function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 9) { 

            var nextItem = $(this).nextAll();

            if (!nextItem.length) { 
                $(content+ '.aantal:eq(0)').focus();
                return false;
            }
            $(this).nextAll().focus();
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**
solved

```
$("body "+content).on("keypress","form.fcheckoutform :input.aantal",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.keyCode === 9) { 
            var nextItem = $(this).parents('.item-checkout').next().children('form').children('div.fr').find('.aantal');
            if (!nextItem.length) { 
                $(content+ ' .aantal:first').focus();
            }else{
                nextItem.focus();
            }
        }
    });
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: .next() should have been enough, it will return 0 or 1 elements based on whether or not there is an element immediately after the selected element.

Comment: next diddn't work for me, it just selected the next element, but not off the same type

Comment: add a selector to .nextAll() to select only the elements that match the current type.

Comment: it works, but I can not check if there is a next element, thats where it breaks, it keeps giving back the number 3 and the the focus go's into the browser

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it. Replace `.parents()` with `.closest()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body "+content).on("keypress","form.fcheckoutform :input.aantal",function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) { 

        var nextItem = $(this).nextUntil(':input.aantal').next();

        if (!nextItem.length) { 
            $(content+ '.aantal:eq(0)').focus();
            return false;
        }
        $(this).nextUntil(':input.aantal').next().focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are the inputs nested in any way? (such as inside divs or labels)

Comment: yes inside div's, you can check www.woonbel.nl - klik left uppercorner

Comment: .next doesn't travers up and down the dom for you, it literally only goes to the very next sibling of the current element. your going to need .parent().next().children() etc. without markup, i can't give code that will work.

Comment: yes, I see now where the 3 stems from, those are the next three items of the containing div. Can I still use nextAll or do I have to look for the index of the element in some way?